# How to play file m3u8 encrypted by AES - 128 while using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I got the URL m3u8 which encrypted by AES - 128 example :

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:4
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:YES
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:14
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="HXa1HNC0GQGsG2Y4INatGdK3TAGsIAC3Gtw4HAPeSQCnTNLcTQK4INw1Ste0HQOsGNHdHXY5TNDeGQLcTASqHtU4INeqHQG1TdG0GXK0SQHfStw0IALbHAZeTgHbSgSrTQPcSdVbHU==.key",IV=0x37386530353837663566623166366230
#EXTINF:10.427089,
https://t5.veeb.xyz/HdKtHXGrHdKtIXStHdKtING4HdStGXGqHdCtGdGqGtKnTdwtHtPdHteqTXVcS2PcIXC1HAY4HgO4GdwqGdY5IAS1S2GqTNwqSNe5HXTgGdG1S2HfINO0G2PfGdVgTXTgGNfdHXVfHNU0GXC2HAK3GdG0GNS2TgC4SNPfTgOrTNYrSgK5G2Y4GAS4TXVgG2ZdGtesIQHeSgO1SdCrTXHfSdK0SQO4HQC4TXPdGdKqIQLcTdY0GNY4StDbGNUsIAG5GNSsSta2HNw4HXCqHgG3HtbcINDgGgY=.css
....
```

from this m3u8 file, I can get key, IV param. I think chuck .ts URL was encrypted also. However, I have no idea about AES - 128 encryption.

Could you guys please help me to play this file by Exoplayer on an Android device?

Thank you

Comment: ExoPlayer should support HLS with AES natively (https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html). Are you able Ito share a link to a video which does not play as it will help people investigate your issue?

Comment: @Mick yeah, this is my link m3u8 https://d9adee54s49yk.cloudfront.net/1a4b6fccda5ab2821c92acc720d8a6a8-0b585afd36405d3a138641070f7048aede47f08a50d3055bacda1d9ec03e10559a9b4320dd567071b4b60056c3c9f48cdc0d0b8a322b08997cfa3d2e340af06982c327911687.m3u8

Comment: That link appears to be broken unfortunately

Comment: yeah, here is new link https://d9adee54s49yk.cloudfront.net/a394150a830d18b75c23ec55677ac42f-063eaa90893dd93bb5fe8138ac1b1766206acc4299765e343b0742fca4ff9d323403cbef21f24f38f8467a275b21d12dfa11283820bc9aa8eb6038433e57dde12ae8d5d2df64.m3u8

Comment: The HLS file at the new link will not play as the URL's to the segments respond with a 404 not found error.

Comment: Any update on this question?